# custom componend as child of my component in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to develop a simple TabsLayout component. This component show all tabs in the header and a single content which is content associated with selected tab.

I want a component where user can import e put childs component like this example:

```
        <TabsLayout tabs={["Description","Flow","History"]} selected="Description">
          <X tab="Description"/>
          <Y tab="Flow"/>
          <Z tab="History"/>
        </TabsLayout>
```

In this case X is visible, and Y and Z are hidden. So the gol is only provide for a dev a simple component called Tabslayout with no callback. I cannot undestrand how to render child becase in this example X,Y,X (for example some div or some semantic-ui components do not render.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as I need to see a 'working' example.  Did you use `ReactDOM.render` at the end?  For example, you can set up a simple React program like this https://codepen.io/pkshreeman/pen/jwEbdO?editors=1011 so we can try to duplicate the results?

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the tabs before they are rendered. Here you have a working example.

```js
const TabsLayout = ({tabs, selected, onSelect, children}) => (
  <div>
    {tabs.map((t) => 
      selected === t
        ? <b>{t} </b>
        : <a href="#" onClick={() => onSelect(t)}>{t} </a>)
    }
    <div>      
      {React.Children.toArray(children).filter(({props}) => selected === props.tab)}
    </div>
  </div>
);

const X = ({tab}) => <div>X: {tab}</div>;
const Y = ({tab}) => <div>Y: {tab}</div>;
const Z = ({tab}) => <div>Z: {tab}</div>;

let selected = 'Description';
function handleSelection(tab) {
  selected = tab;
  renderTabs();
}

function renderTabs() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <TabsLayout 
      tabs={["Description","Flow","History"]} 
      selected={selected}
      onSelect={handleSelection}
    >    
      <X tab="Description"/>
      <Y tab="Flow"/>
      <Z tab="History"/>
    </TabsLayout>, 
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
}

renderTabs();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all for help me but I found the solution.
Simply, I call

> return this.props.children.find((child) => child.props.tab ===
>   this.state.selected);

where state.selected is selectedProps of TabsLayout when I did open this Question.